# Swift class available switch depending on iOS version for UICollectionViewCell vs UICollectionViewListCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewlistcell

For iOS13 my cell class is UICollectionViewCell, and in iOS14 i want the same class to be UICollectionViewListCell, which is available only in iOS14 for the list layout, that i am using under iOS14

Is there a way of achieving it?

Note: this is a simple case, but i have many cells, so having 2 different classes for each iOS is not an option

```
@available(iOS 13, *)
class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
}

@available(iOS 14, *)
class MyCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    
}
```

Comment: I think I disagree with both the answer and your thought about options. Yes, the answer works, but depending on how things are coded you will potentially have **many** `#if` clauses throughout your code. The easiest IMHO may well be to have separate classes, with a single `#if` surrounding it. One other option? Fork the project into to. Deploy one for iOS 13, followed by one for iOS 14. Users on iOS 13 will never see the forked project.

Comment: @dfd if what you mean by "fork" is to fork the project repo, that has its own headaches.  I would probably place the version dependent code in separate Swift packages which are conditionally imported once at the top of the file.  However, best solution for a given project depends on the project's structure and will probably need to be rethought as the project evolves.  Supporting multiple os versions or multiple platforms in a single code base is never going to be pretty.  It's just a matter of picking the best place to put the "ugly"

Comment: @ChipJarred, I can easily agree with your comment, and I think you agree (somewhat) with mine. It's a headache, and, depending on the code structure, not pretty. (That code structure wasn't part of the question, and while not a reason to downvote, makes it difficult to provide the best option as an answer.) The easiest "answer"? Probably to drop support for iOS 13, which is too early (for many) by about 6 months. Anyone on iOS 13 would still have a working app, but those with an iOS version that can use `UICollectionViewListCell` will be able to download the new version.

Comment: Yeah, for an app it's a relatively easy call to drop old os support in one or two major os versions.  It's a harder problem for libraries, because by indirection their end customers are all of the customers of all of the apps that use that library.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is conditionally compile one or the other, so what you need is something that has this form:

```swift
#if os(iOS)
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000
        @available(iOS 14, *)
        class MyCell: UICollectionViewListCell { }
    #else
        @available(iOS 13, *)
        class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell { }
    #endif
#else
// Maybe cases here for macOS, tvOS, watchOS
#endif
```

Comment: i get the "Expected '&&' or '||' expression" for the __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 140000